# Xamarin.Android app crashes when trying to debug

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working in a Xamarin.Android app using Visual Studio Community 2022 for Windows (Version 17.1.5) and I'm facing a problem when I try to debug any piece of code.

The app works fine, there's even a version working on PlayStore for some years now, but when I try to debug VisualStudio hits the breakpoint and after 1 or 2 seconds the app just crashes making impossible to inspect variables or just do a step-by-step debbuging. It's kinda frustrating being unable to properly test my code.

I've been working with Xamarin.Android for like 4 years now and I know debugging Android or iOS apps always has been tricky, but I was able to go through it, this time debug my app is just impossible.

Please help!

Comment: have you looked at the device logs?  I'm not sure what you expect us to tell you based on what you've posted.

Comment: Its in the middle of a UI update, isn't it? Processing some user action? For testing, try temporarily wrapping the entire body of the command or event handler in  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, so that the original user action is allowed to return to XF and the OS, before it executes the code you are breakpointing. (If you wrap just some of the code instead of all of it, keep in mind that any code that isn't wrapped, will execute before the wrapped part . I mean "A, BeginInvoke(B), C" will execute in order "A, C, B".)

Comment: It is not in the middle of a UI update nor processing a user action, I'm just trying to debug a Firebase Cloud Messaging configuration where I've replaced some obsolete code. Weird thing is no matter where I place a breakpoint the app always crashes a couple seconds after the debugger hits the breakpoint.
Anyway I'll try your suggestion, thank u Steve!

Comment: Same issue here.